# How to convert this recurrence solution to divide and conquer?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

How to solve this question:

> Given n balloons, indexed from 0 to n-1. Each balloon is painted with
>   a number on it represented by array nums. You are asked to burst all
>   the balloons. If the you burst balloon i you will get nums[left] *
>   nums[right] coins. Here left and right are adjacent indices of i.
>   After the burst, the left and right then becomes adjacent.If you burst
>   the corner balloons then you will get the points that are adjacent to
>   those balloons.If you burst the last balloon then you will get the
>   amount of points written on it.  Find the maximum coins you can
>   collect by bursting the balloons wisely.

Sample test case :

```
{1,2,3,4}
20
{5,7,8}
56
```

I have tried this solution using recursion which seems to give the correct answer:

```
public static int maxCoints(List<Integer> list) {
        int max = 0;
        if (list.size() == 1) {
            return list.get(0);
        }
        if(list.size() == 2) {
            return Math.max(list.get(0),list.get(1))*2;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int left = i == 0 ? 1 : list.get(i-1);
            int right = i == list.size()-1 ? 1 : list.get(i+1);
            int n = left * right;
            List<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>(list);
            tmp.remove(i);
            max = Math.max(max, n + maxCoints(tmp));
        }
        return max;
    }
```

But I have tried this solution for divide and conquer but it seems to give wrong answer for the first test case this gives answer as 17 instead of 20

```
int find(vector<int>& v, int L, int R) {
    int ans = 0;
    // if(L==R)    return v[L];
    for (int i = L; i <= R; i++) {
        int l = find(v, L, i-1);
        int r = find(v, i+1, R);
        int val = v[L-1]*v[R+1] + l + r;
        ans = max(ans, val);
    }
    return ans;
}

int32_t main() {
fast_io;
    ll tt;  cin >> tt;
    while(tt--) {
        ll n;   cin >> n;
        vector<int> v(n+2,1);
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            cin >> v[i];
        }
        cout << find(v,1,n) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me figure out the mistake.

Comment: **Moderator note**: do not vandalise posts; as per the terms and conditions it has been licensed to the site the moment you posted it.  We do not delete questions once they have accrued answers, as the posted solutions may prove helpful to future visitors.

Comment: (And it appears I accidentally cleared your flag requesting deletion last night, which would ordinarily have been declined. My apologies if this caused confusion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the a minor modification of the [burst balloons problem on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/burst-balloons/) which I wrote the editorial solution to.

Recursion will work but for our intents and purposes it is too slow. Recursively removing every balloon and caching gives us `2^N` states, which is the power set of our balloons. We'd like to solve this problem in polynomial time.

Divide and conquer is definitely the right idea.

- After bursting balloon `i`, we can divide the problem into the balloons to the left of `i` (`nums[0:i]`) and to the right of `i` (`nums[i+1:]`).
- To find the optimal solution we check every optimal solution after bursting each balloon.
- Since we will find the optimal solution for every range in nums, and we burst every balloon in every range to find the optimal solution, we have an `O(N^2)` ranges times `O(N)` time per range which is a `O(N^3)` solution
- However, if we try to divide our problem in the order where we burst balloons first, we run into an issue. As balloons burst, the adjacency of other balloons changes. We are unable to keep track of what balloons the endpoints of our intervals are adjacent to. This is where your solution has issues.

To elaborate on that last point:

When you do:

```
int l = find(v, L, i-1);
```

You might not actually get the optimal solution. Consider that balloon `i - 1` is now adjacent to balloon `i + 1` after you've burst balloon `i`. If you then burst balloon `i - 1`, balloon `i - 2` is now adjacent to balloon `i + 1`. If you attempt divide on every balloon burst, your `find` has to somehow still consider balloons outside the range `[L, R]`.

To solve this instead of bursting balloons and dividing we consider adding balloons into an initially empty interval in reverse the order that they were burst.

Let `dp(i, j)` denote the maximum score on `[i, j]`. For each balloon `k` on `[i + 1, j - 1]`, we add it into the interval and compute the score. After we add the balloon we can always then divide the problem into `[i, k]` and `[k, j]`, because the left and right boundaries are known. This gets rid of adjacency issues.

A trickier part is to fulfill "if you burst the last balloon then you will get the amount of points written on it." We manually iterate over the last balloon we burst and apply divide and conquer as with before.

See the code to get a better idea:

```
class Solution {
    public int maxCoins(int[] nums) {

        int n = nums.length + 2;
        int[] new_nums = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            new_nums[i+1] = nums[i];
        }

        new_nums[0] = new_nums[n - 1] = 1;

        // cache the results of dp
        int[][] memo = new int[n][n];

        // find the maximum number of coins obtained from adding all balloons from (0, len(nums) - 1)
        int ans = 0;

        // manually burst the last balloon because it has special rules
        for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
            ans = Math.max(ans, new_nums[i] + dp(memo, new_nums, i, n - 1) + dp(memo, new_nums, 0, i));
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public int dp(int[][] memo, int[] nums, int left, int right) {
        // no more balloons can be added
        if (left + 1 == right) return 0;

        // we've already seen this, return from cache
        if (memo[left][right] > 0) return memo[left][right];

        // add each balloon on the interval and return the maximum score
        int ans = 0;
        for (int i = left + 1; i < right; ++i)
            ans = Math.max(ans, nums[left] * nums[right]
            + dp(memo, nums, left, i) + dp(memo, nums, i, right));
        // add to the cache
        memo[left][right] = ans;
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 7, 8]
```

Output:

```
20
56
```